# Error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]

Tags: java, csv, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to get CSV data from Azure Blob storage using Embulk.

I get the following error, please tell me how to solve it.

I don't know what caused the error.

It seemed that the CSV reference was made.

Embulk command execution result

```
PS C:\Users\XXXXXX> C:\Users\XXXXXX\Embulk_bundle\embulk.bat run -b C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Embulk_bundle\bundle C:\Users\XXXXXX\Embulk_bundle\config\sample.yml
2021-12-03 13:46:09.802 +0900: Embulk v0.9.23
2021-12-03 13:46:10.888 +0900 [WARN] (main): DEPRECATION: JRuby org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer is directly injected.
2021-12-03 13:46:13.686 +0900 [INFO] (main): BUNDLE_GEMFILE is being set: "C:\Users\XXXXXX\Embulk_bundle\bundle\Gemfile"
2021-12-03 13:46:13.694 +0900 [INFO] (main): Gem's home and path are being cleared.
2021-12-03 13:46:15.513 +0900 [INFO] (main): Started Embulk v0.9.23
2021-12-03 13:46:15.701 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-input-azure_blob_storage (0.3.1)
2021-12-03 13:46:15.801 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Loaded plugin embulk-output-postgresql (0.9.0)
2021-12-03 13:46:16.526 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): add file to the request list: XXXXXX/XXXXXXX/20211115/part-00000-tid-8457700275164717816-fc017e47-6ecb-46aa-be90-60e0a3847af7-1521-1-c000.csv.gz
2021-12-03 13:46:16.608 +0900 [INFO] (0001:transaction): Using local thread executor with max_threads=4 / output tasks 2 = input tasks 1 * 2
org.embulk.exec.PartialExecutionException: org.embulk.config.ConfigException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$LoaderState.buildPartialExecuteException(BulkLoader.java:340)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doRun(BulkLoader.java:566)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.access$000(BulkLoader.java:35)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:353)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$1.run(BulkLoader.java:350)
        at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:22)
        at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.run(BulkLoader.java:350)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:242)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.runInternal(EmbulkRunner.java:291)
        at org.embulk.EmbulkRunner.run(EmbulkRunner.java:155)
        at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.runSubcommand(EmbulkRun.java:431)
        at org.embulk.cli.EmbulkRun.run(EmbulkRun.java:90)
        at org.embulk.cli.Main.main(Main.java:64)
        Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.doCleanup(BulkLoader.java:463)
                at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$3.run(BulkLoader.java:397)
                at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader$3.run(BulkLoader.java:394)
                at org.embulk.spi.Exec.doWith(Exec.java:22)
                at org.embulk.exec.BulkLoader.cleanup(BulkLoader.java:394)
                at org.embulk.EmbulkEmbed.run(EmbulkEmbed.java:245)
                ... 5 more
```

CSV sample in Azure

```
Mesh100ID,CityOaza,Pref,Dim5,YamaLine,WeekDate,cnt_All,cnt_OK,cnt_NG,cnt_AOK,cnt_ANG,cnt_LOK,cnt_LNG,cnt_G,cnt_S,_G_RATE,La_OT,wkt
36225769203,XXXXXX,XXXX,XXXXX,,9999/11/08,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.0,0,"POLYGON ((122.9975 24.4666666666667, 122.99875 24.4666666666667, 122.99875 24.4675, 122.9975 24.4675, 122.9975 24.4666666666667))"
36233720112,XXXXX,XXXXXX,XXX,,9999/11/08,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0.0,0,"POLYGON ((123.8775 24.2675, 123.87875 24.2675, 123.87875 24.2683333333333, 123.8775 24.2683333333333, 123.8775 24.2675))"
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is `Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token`, So probably your configuration is incorrect.
Check your configuration again.

Expected value (Hash)

```yaml
  key: value
```

(Maybe) Your configuration. (incorrect)

```yaml
  - key: value
```